# Why does sshd give a different identification when connecting through netcat?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have been attempting to create a way to ssh into a machine hiding behind a firewall. I set up my ssh client with the option `Proxycommand /usr/bin/ncat -l 2000`, and then I connect it to sshd with `ncat <client> 2000 -c "sshd -i"` on the server. It works in that I can get a shell on the server, but the server sends a different key than when I use normal ssh. So the question is, why? Is the key different when sshd is called in this unusual way?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how your network setup looks like.. Are you connecting from a client to the firewall on port 2000? Give us a clearer idea what you do on the server and what you do on the client...

Comment: I'm fairly certain the network is irrelevent

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the ProxyCommand functionality in ssh(d) but the above configuration sounds backwards to me. Why would the client be listening for connections? Why would the server know about the client IP address ahead of time?

It would seem to me that the client ssh_config should specify the ncat that connects to a port on the server, no?

Comment: That's exactly the point. The server is behind a firewall, so it can't listen for ssh connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment the `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key` line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to have `sshd -i` use the correct key.

Answer (score 1):

In my test case it's not different:

```
~$ ssh -v localhost
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 59:ca:86:5a:c0:01:f9:8e:31:3e:0b:8e:cf:ad:2b:fa

~$ ssh -v localhost -p 2000
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 59:ca:86:5a:c0:01:f9:8e:31:3e:0b:8e:cf:ad:2b:fa
```

Where on the port 2000 it's invoked as `/usr/sbin/sshd -i` from `xinetd`.

Maybe in your case it reads a different config file? Try adding `-f /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to the ncat command line and see if it helps.

Solution: Apparently sshd was using a different key when invoked from ncat, `sshd -i -h /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key` does the trick.

Comment: If i do as you did i get the expected result. The error only comes about when connecting under these specific circumstances. Although, when i next get the chance i'll try what you've suggested

Comment: Also, i can't imagine posting that key is safe, unless you've garbled it. Or it's safe because it's some kind of hash value and i'm just a moron

Comment: @RobbieMckennie - no worries, it's a hash of the public part of the server key, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography for info about Public Key Cryptography. Actually there is a way to store these hashes in DNS for host verification, see https://simon.butcher.name/archives/2011/01/16/SSH-key-fingerprints-in-DNS so it's by all means a non-sensitive info.

Comment: Adding `-f /etc/ssh/sshd_config` didn't help

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure the key is different? I did exactly what you did: `ssh -v -o ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/ncat -l 2000' blah` (literally with 'blah' - it doesn't matter what hostname you use) and got the very same key fingerprint as above: `The authenticity of host 'blah (<no hostip for proxy command>)' can't be established.` and `ECDSA key fingerprint is 59:ca:86:5a:c0:01:f9:8e:31:3e:0b:8e:cf:ad:2b:fa.` Perhaps it only prompts you because the hostname differs? Run the client with -v and check the actual fingerprints.

Comment: `debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 06:96:9f:7f:47:df:41:fb:d0:ae:af:e6:d6:af:87:e0` and 
`debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e1:ed:fc:e2:03:9a:2d:7c:47:81:c0:79:c1:0e:ac:a5`

Comment: How did you get these? One test is `ssh -v localhost` on the server and the second one must be `ssh -v -o ProxyCommand=...` - that way you'll talk to the same ssh daemon. Is this what you did?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i did.

Comment: Is mammon the server that also runs `ncat mammon 2000 -c "sshd -i"`? Or are they two different machines?

Comment: For the purposes of testing they are the same machine, but i plan to use this arrangement on different machines all together.

Comment: Can you do `/usr/sbin/sshd -i -h /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key` to force it to use the right key?

Comment: I can! So, where was sshd getting it's key before? :S

Comment: It seems that the different ways of running sshd have different host key defaults. I uncommented `#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and voila! All is right again in the universe.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, finally. (btw I wouldn't mind your upping or accepting this answer - I still get excited by rep points ;)